# How can I tell which version of Varnish I'm running?

Tags: cache, varnish

How can I get the installed Varnish cache version string from the command line?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

According to the varnish [documentation](https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/reference/varnishd.html#options), it's `varnishd -V`

Comment: Thanks! In case anyone is as brilliant as me, make sure you're using a capital "V". I couldn't figure it out because I was using a lowercase one. [bonk!]

Comment: I need to find _varnishd_ first, so I used _locate_. It was located at _/usr/sbin/varnishd_ .

Comment: You might also need to run it as root or with sudo

Answer (score 3):

`varnishd -V`

This will return you something like:

```
varnishd (varnish-4.1.5 revision 2c82b1c)
Copyright (c) 2006 Verdens Gang AS
Copyright (c) 2006-2015 Varnish Software AS
```

Comment: Option `-V` is already the accepted answer.